# Is it safe to expose the AWS Cognito Ids?

Tags: javascript, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using the client-side Cognito Javascript SDK.  Part of the setup requires configuring `region, UserPoolId, ClientId, and identityPoolId`.  During testing, I'm including the data via a separate file that users could look through and use to discover these Cognito ids.

Is it safe to expose these ids to the end user?

Otherwise, how do I do this safely?

Comment: No, It is not safe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a post by AWS on their forums that addresses this.

> Please note that with userPoolId and clientId, only unauthenticated APIs can be called, for eg: SignUp, authenticate, forgotPassword etc. So userPoolId and clientId alone are not enough to do any malicious activity on your user pool.

Source is https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245752&tstart=200

An alternative is to use API Gateway with the Cognito authorizer for handling calls to other back-end services (like DynamoDB or S3) instead of using those directly from the front-end js.  That's described here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-mobile-app-backend-with-hybrid-apps/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using authenticated identities (when you use Cognito User Pools, then it is authenticated identities), then even if the an attacker gets hold of identityId, they cannot get AWS credentials without providing the id token which can only be obtained by providing authentication credentials (username and password).

P.S: It is always advised to use authenticated identities and even if you have a use case for unauthenticated identities, it is better to keep the access to minimal in the role for unauthenticated identities.

Comment: I am using authenticated identities. I am not exposing my aws credentials. How do I avoid exposing `region, UserPoolId, ClientId, and identityPoolId`?

Comment: I dont think there's any harm in exposing these. Even AWS Amplify has aws-exports.js file stored n client side which has all these values including your dyanmodb table name, api paths, s3 bucket name, etc

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution by invoke particular lambda function using IAM unauth credential. So the flow like this :

1. Create a cognito identity pool for unauthenticated provider
2. Associated that cognito identity pool to IAM Role Policy for unauthenticated amr
3. Give permission actions for that IAM Role to invoke lambda authentication function (login, signup, forgot, confirm, etc)

So here, the client apps only need get their unauthenticated credential identity to invoke the lambda authentication function. We store the clientID & userPoolID on the lambda, not on client apps

Comment: I dont think there's any harm in exposing these. Even AWS Amplify has aws-exports.js file stored n client side which has all these values including your dyanmodb table name, api paths, s3 bucket name, etc

Comment: exposing the confidence datas on client (most specific UserPoolID & IdentityPoolID), let the users to reuse it and do the DDOS test (in the range of expired session). Once I know UserPoolID + ClientID, I can do CURL to OAUTH2 API to generate tokens. Once I know IdentityPoolId, I Will exchange my tokens to temp credentials. Then, I will find out the activated resources to send as much as request with my nodejs scripts or recursive aws cli. With API Gateway we can't prevent this by throttle API and WAF. Direct request doesn't have rules for throttling

Comment: I just expose my ClientID on the client apps to request an OAUTH2 grant code. I forward the code to Lambda through HTTP API Gateway and leave the rest parts on Lambda to request tokens, credentials exchange, doing encoding and some other techniques to make sure everything robust and safe. But, I don't even feel safe yet. More security concerns and robust systems there rather that just deliver an Apps

Comment: I agree with you, however we should note that expert & senior AWS engineers have been developing AWS Amplify framework. They store aws-exports.js file on client which has everything - dynamdb table name, s3 bucket name, userpool id, identity pool id, userpool client id, etc

Comment: Also see this issue on AWS amplify github - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2495 - It basically okays storing these info on client side.